# I try to learn pipe in c language on linux

Tags: c, linux, pipeline

I try to learn pipeline in c language on linux . 
I write follow program. 
Are there any error in this program?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>


int main (void)
{
    int fd[2], nbytes;
    pid_t childpid;
    char string[]= "Hello, World!\n";
    char readbuffer[80];


    pipe(fd);

    if((childpid = fork()) == -1)
    {
        perror("fork");
        exit(0);    
    } 

    if(childpid == 0)
    {
        // child process closes up input side of pipe.
        close(fd[0]);

        // send "string" through the output side of pipe.
        write(fd[1], string, strlen(string));
        exit(0);
    }

    else
    {
        // parent process closes up output side of pipe.
        close(fd[0]);

        // Read in a string from pipe.
        nbytes = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
        printf("Received string = %s\n", readbuffer);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any problem?

Comment: Hi, if the system tells you your post doesn't have enough context, don't just copy-paste that message, **add more context**. Does your code work? Does it do what you want? If so, this post is off-topic here. If not, what are the problems? Errors? Unexpected output?

Comment: `write(fd[1], string, 1+strlen(string));`

Comment: @wildplasser: only if he wants the `'\0'` to go down the pipe.  More significantly, it should print: `printf("Received string = %.*s\n", nbytes, readbuffer);` to only print the data that was read.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I know that; I was only hinting the OP in the right direction. Trusting on buffers to contain terminating NUL's is waiting for disasters to happen. Your solution is cleaner, of course. (BTW what does printf do when nbytes < 0 ? Ignored? assumed 0? Implementation dependant? )

Comment: @wildplasser: For `nbytes < 0`, you probably get into undefined behaviour — a point covered in my answer by avoiding that `printf()` with a negative length.  I chose to avoid a zero length too, even though that is fully defined behaviour, AFAIK.

Comment: Your answer has a typo in it.

Comment: Hmm...closer scrutiny of the 2011 standard shows: _§7.21.6.1 The `fprintf()` function ¶5 As noted above, a field width, or precision, or both, may be indicated by an asterisk. In
this case, an `int` argument supplies the field width or precision. The arguments
specifying field width, or precision, or both, shall appear (in that order) before the
argument (if any) to be converted. A negative field width argument is taken as a `-` flag
followed by a positive field width. A negative precision argument is taken as if the
precision were omitted._

Comment: Consequently, the negative precision is allowed but ignored, which means that the string must be null terminated after all (which is not guaranteed in the example program).

Answer (score 1):

One of these two segments of code is incorrect, simply based on the comments:

```
if (childpid == 0)
{
    // child process closes up input side of pipe.
    close(fd[0]);
```

and:

```
else
{
    // parent process closes up output side of pipe.
    close(fd[0]);
```

You actually need to close `fd[1]` in the parent (the writing end).  Surprisingly, your `read` call is correct, but is reading from the file descriptor you just closed in the original.

Note that you should only print what you read (and only if you read something successfully):

```
if (nbytes > 0)
    printf("Received string: <<%.*s>>\n", nbytes, readbuffer);
else if (nbytes == 0)
    printf("Received no data\n");
else
    printf("Received error (%d: %s)\n", errno, strerror(errno));
```

(Note that you'd need both `<errno.h>` and `<string.h>` for the last line to compile correctly.)

The `<<` and `>>` markers are there simply so you can see trailing blanks, etc.  You can omit them if you prefer.

Comment: Dont forget `if (nbytes > 0) { readbuffer[nbytes] = 0;
    printf("Received string: <<%s>>\n", nbytes, readbuffer);}` (or the asterix, off course...)

Comment: The null termination is not needed; the `.*` was missing.